# Angular path between tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

Considering the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

 \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc,shapes,matrix,backgrounds,arrows,shadows,
   positioning,fit,automata,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta,bending,quotes,shadows.blur}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Server Operating Systems}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[draw,circle,align=center,font=\large,shading=radial,
    outer color=blue!55,middle color=blue!50,inner color=blue!20,
    minimum size=1.5cm] at (5,0) (a) {A};

    \node[draw,circle,align=center,font=\large,shading=radial,minimum size=1cm,
    outer color=blue!55,middle color=blue!50,inner color=blue!20,left=.5cm of a,
    font=\scriptsize] (b) {B};

    \node[draw,circle,align=center,font=\large,shading=radial,minimum size=1cm,
    outer color=blue!55,middle color=blue!50,inner color=blue!20,above=.5cm of a,
    font=\scriptsize] (c) {C};

    \node[draw,circle,align=center,font=\large,shading=radial,minimum size=1cm,
    outer color=blue!55,middle color=blue!50,inner color=blue!20,right=.5cm of a,
    font=\scriptsize] (d) {D};

    \node[draw,circle,align=center,font=\large,shading=radial,minimum size=1cm,
    outer color=blue!55,middle color=blue!50,inner color=blue!20,below=.5cm of a,
    font=\scriptsize] (e) {e};

    \draw[-,ultra thick,draw] (b.north) .. controls ($(b|-c)+(.7,-.5)$) .. (c.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How one can draw a ring which goes from b.north to c.west, c.east to d.north, d.south to e.east and e.west to b.south?

Answer (score 3):

It could be another case for [`smartdiagram`](http://ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{planet color=orange!60,
distance planet-satellite=3cm,
font=\scriptsize
}
\smartdiagram[connected constellation diagram]
{A,B,C,D,E}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the syntax `(coord1) to[out=<angle>,in=<angle>] (coord2)`, as in

```
    \draw (b.north) to[out=90,in=180]  (c.west)
          (c.east)  to[out=0,in=90]    (d.north)
          (d.south) to[out=270,in=0]   (e.east)
          (e.west)  to[out=180,in=270] (b.south);
```

If you want an actual circle through the centers of the nodes, you can add the `through` library, and use

```
\scoped[on background layer]
   \node [circle through=(c.center),draw,red] at (a.center) {};
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

 \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc,shapes,matrix,backgrounds,arrows,shadows,
   positioning,fit,automata,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta,bending,quotes,shadows.blur}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Server Operating Systems}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[draw,circle,align=center,font=\large,shading=radial,
    outer color=blue!55,middle color=blue!50,inner color=blue!20,
    minimum size=1.5cm] at (5,0) (a) {A};

    \node[draw,circle,align=center,font=\large,shading=radial,minimum size=1cm,
    outer color=blue!55,middle color=blue!50,inner color=blue!20,left=.5cm of a,
    font=\scriptsize] (b) {B};

    \node[draw,circle,align=center,font=\large,shading=radial,minimum size=1cm,
    outer color=blue!55,middle color=blue!50,inner color=blue!20,above=.5cm of a,
    font=\scriptsize] (c) {C};

    \node[draw,circle,align=center,font=\large,shading=radial,minimum size=1cm,
    outer color=blue!55,middle color=blue!50,inner color=blue!20,right=.5cm of a,
    font=\scriptsize] (d) {D};

    \node[draw,circle,align=center,font=\large,shading=radial,minimum size=1cm,
    outer color=blue!55,middle color=blue!50,inner color=blue!20,below=.5cm of a,
    font=\scriptsize] (e) {e};

    \draw (b.north) to[out=90,in=180]  (c.west)
          (c.east)  to[out=0,in=90]    (d.north)
          (d.south) to[out=270,in=0]   (e.east)
          (e.west)  to[out=180,in=270] (b.south);

    \scoped[on background layer]
        \node [circle through=(c.center),draw,red] at (a.center) {};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```